# Accessing a Local Directory from an Asp Net Core RC2 Website Using IIS

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, directory, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an Asp Net Core RC2 website that reads some files from a directory local to the server (we'll say `C:\temp`).  While I can get this to work just fine running from Visual Studio, it will not work when deployed to a `C:\inetpub\myWebSite` (running within IIS 10.0).

I have tried every researched permissions aspect from StackOverflow and elsewhere that I could find, including giving permissions to my `IIS APPPOOL\myAppPoolName`, `IUSR`, and `IIS_IUSRS` (I can see these users have effective read access, both in advanced permissions editing and sharing).  I have tried both a virtual directory and a physical directory within the content root of the website.  I have tried altering Anonymous Authentication identity to be both the `IUSR` and the Application Pool identity.

Try as I might, I cannot get it to read out of the directory as an IIS Application website the same as I can in Debug mode within Visual Studio (both the IIS Express and Console Application versions function as intended). Note that the website runs as intended otherwise from within IIS.  Also note that there are no apparent errors; everything appears to function normally, but it is clear that the data was not read.

I am about 90% confident it is a permissions issue or a related IIS setup issue.  There could be something unique about the segregation between IIS and Kestrel that I am just unaware of that is affecting my ability to achieve what I want.

Any helpful ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I am back to trying to address this issue.  I have discovered that the application is able to move the files in question, so it definitely has permission to read them.

I ran SQL Server Profiler and it appears that the problem is that when the application calls a Procedure, it fails to even hit the database, but I am still not receiving any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I realized it wasn't hitting the database, I figured it was an IIS issue.  I first attempted to set up an `IIS APPPOOL\<AppPoolName>` Login for SQL Server, but didn't have any success.  Then I resorted to running the AppPool that the Web Application was in under a user that had access to the database and this worked.

The steps are as follows:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Navigate on the left to `Application Pools`
3. Right-click on the Application Pool that your application is running in and select `Advanced Settings...`
4. Under `Process Model` > `Identity` click in the box to the right of it and an ellipsis (three dots) will appear; click that to open an `Application Pool Identity` window
5. Select the 'Custom Account`radio button and click`Set...` and type in the username and password you wish to use and have the AppPool run as (that has access to the database).

As an aside, remember if you're running a .NET Core Application to set your AppPool to `No Managed Code`.